# Why components SCSS doesn't apply Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hellow guys,

I have a page in my new Ionic App where I have a ion-card, so I want to change the background of the card inside the component .scss but doesn't change anything.

The weird thing is that if I put the same in global.scss it works, could someone explain me what's happening?

Here's my move.page.html

```
<ion-content>
<div class="move-container">
  <div class="row moveCard">
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
          This is content, without any paragraph or header tags,
          within an ion-card-content element.
        </ion-card-content>
      </ion-card>
  </div>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

move.page.scss

```
ion-card {
    --background: blue !important;
}
```

For your imformation im using angular routing with lazy loading (I don't know if that affects)

Comment: i see a spelling mistake `--brackground` should be `--background` in your .scss

Comment: @ChetanBansal Sorry that was my mistake asking the quesiton in the code is correc, but i try to chang the scss of other components and still Ionic make what he wants. I pretty new to Ionic I don't know what to change to use my styles in the components

Comment: what is the selector name that is being declared in the component of your page. Are you using the ion-card selector within the scope of your page selector? Also try changing --background: blue to background: blue.